# How do I use a service method return as ng-options?

Tags: angularjs

I am getting back a list of customers from the database and updating a select list with them.

cshtml:

```
<select ng-model="model.customerKey" ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in model.customers"></select>
```

controller method:

```
$scope.getCustomers = function (customerType) {
            customerService.get(customerType).then(function (results) {
                $scope.model.customers = results;
            });
```

I am choosing between three types of customers with radio buttons

```
<div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="customerOption in options">
    <input type="radio" id="{{customerOption.Value}}" name="customer" ng-change="getCustomers(model.customerType)" ng-model="model.customerType" ng-value="customerOption.Key" ng-checked="customerOption.Checked" />{{customerOption.Value}}
</div>
```

If I do the above then the list doesn't update, because angular's watchers don't recognize the change in the list.

How do I use the method call to populate the ng-options?

```
$scope.getCustomers = function (customerType) {
        customerService.get(customerType).then(function (results) {
            return results;
        });
```

this doesn't seem to work:

```
<select ng-model="model.customerKey" ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in getCustomers(customerType)"></select>
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is your return statement is in the wrong scope

```
$scope.getCustomers = function (customerType) {
    customerService.get(customerType).then(**function** (results) {
        return results;
    });
```

The return statement is the return of the ** function not of getCustomers(). I believe the following should fix the issue:

```
$scope.getCustomers = function (customerType) {
    return customerService.get(customerType).then(function (results) {
        return results;
    });
```

---

The other solution to this problem would be to define a custom filter on customerType and use:

```
<select ng-model="model.customerKey" 
ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in model.customers | customerTypeFilter:selectedType"></select>
```

The filter:

```
angular.module('superCoolFilter')
    .filter('customerTypeFilter', function () {
        return function (objects, selectedType) {

            return objects.filter(function(item){
                return item.customerType == selectedType;
            };
        }
    });
```

Personally, I'd suggest the custom filter because to avoids a second API call

Comment: So the main problem I am having is the CustomerOptions and the Customer cshtml are on separate partial views. I am trying to use the service as the renderer so that the watch sees both

Comment: Did the first part of my solution yield any results? I can understand why the filter option wouldn't work for you, but fixing that method should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is a scoping issue.

You should consider using `ng-controller="<ControllerName> as <ThisRef>"`

So in your controller you would do something like this:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
   var control = this;
   control.hello = "Hello World";
});
```

Then in your HTML something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as mc">
   {{mc.hello}}
</body>
```

It is not clear right a way why that is better until you deal with what you are dealing with right now.

Here is what I believe is an example that solves your issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/FsSbbmXEPAsNGNwx9HKw?p=preview

Notice that I use the "as" word and use "mc" to access everything.

I set that in my controller by assigning everything to "this" or "mc" to make it more readable.

If you take that exact code and swap it to use $scope it will not work.

I hope that helps!

Comment: So the main problem I am having is the CustomerOptions and the Customer cshtml are on separate partial views. I am trying to use the service as the renderer so that the watch sees both